# Looking for video editor that can export specific segments of video

Tags: video

I am looking to export the opening themes of some anime I like to watch. Can you tell me a software that is easy to use and can do this? I currently have the episodes downloaded on my computer. I am not very good with Ubuntu so hopefully the program won't involve a lot of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a big fan of avconv under the package libav-tools. Begin with installation using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools vlc
```

I am suggesting 'vlc' because it installs lots of libraries for handling many different file types. But you can use your favorite media player to play/test your videos. Once installed enter this command to verify a successful install:

```
avconv -version
```

What's the format of the videos you're trying to edit? Please post the output of: (NOTE: type the ACTUAL name of the video including whatever file extension it has. ie. anime.mov, or clip.mkv, etc..)

```
avconv -i your_movie.mp4
```

Now that you have the tools you need, let's hack up your video the way you want. For example, if you'd like to take a 10 second clip starting at 9 minutes and 57 seconds, you would use this command:

```
avconv -ss 00:09:57 -t 00:00:10 -i movie.mp4 -codec copy movie_clip.mp4
```

The basic format is:

```
avconv -i [input file] -ss [start time] -t [duration] -codec copy [output file]
```

Notice that we copied the 'codec' so that the ouput clip has the same audio/video codecs as the original. If you wanted to take a clip, AND output a different format, you could do this:

```
avconv -ss 00:09:57 -t 00:00:10 -i movie.mp4 -c:a libvorbis -c:v libtheora movie_clip.ogv
```

The file extension '.ogv' is the proper container for the codecs we are converting to. This gets a bit tricky but with a little research and trial & error, you can get pretty savvy with these command line tools for editing audio/video. I would check out the [avconv manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html) for a great place to begin learning these skills. There is also mencoder, which is just as powerful and versatile - you can find more information at the [mencoder manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mencoder).

Good luck, and enjoy!

Comment: I used your method but I found that the exported video always skipped the first 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I use VLC. It's easy and cross platform.

> sudo apt-get install vlc

See this [cutting video with VLC tutorial](http://www.guidingtech.com/8802/use-vlc-as-video-cuting-tool/) fur a detailed explanation.